# Eclipse - Shortcut that toggles between Caller and Callee Hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse provides the shortcut "Ctrl + Alt + H" that opens the Call Hierarchy.  I find this very helpful, however, I often find myself needing to toggle between the Caller Hierarchy, and the Callee Hierarchy.  Is there a way to do this without mouse-clicking on the respective icons?

Answer (score 1):

From caller to callee:

I do "Ctrl + click" to trace down. Or "Ctrl + T" to check for implementations of an interface.

From callee to caller:

I will put the cursor inside callee's method name: "Ctrl + Shift + G" will search for all the callers.